# Error when opening Screen Time on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ventura, screen-time

I get this error when opening Screen Time on my Mac:

[image: screen time error message]

`The URL "prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME" is missing a hostname.`

I just upgraded to Mac Os X Ventura 13.0.1; Screen Time has never worked since the upgrade.

Any suggestions on how to get Screen Time working again?

Answer (score 0):

This has two questions in one, but I can answer the one shown in the screenshot.

Your Shortcut is not working because that's not the URL scheme for System Settings on macOS. The correct URL for Screen Time in Ventura is:

`x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Screen-Time-Settings.extension`

Which will work if you put it in a Shortcut like you have.

[image: Screenshot of the URL in a Shortcut]

Comment: Hmm I just opened the link that came up when I search "Screen Time" in Spotlight. I thought this was the standard Screen Time app, but perhaps a while ago (I've had this computer a long time) I created a shortcut to Screen Time that I've forgotten about.